# Streaming local files via HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, streaming

I am trying to write something that will allow me to stream files using my browser using HTML5, but so far I have no luck. It works if I host the files somewhere, or but it in the site's directory, but I want to be able to play files from anywhere no my PC.

Here is my most recent attempt:

```
<audio id="player" src="file:///c:/test.mp3" controls autoplay autobuffer>Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>
```

using a hosted file works fine, and going to file:///c:/test.mp3 in my browser window works fine, but the two combined doesn't work.

I have tried just about every combination I can think of, including:

```
<audio id="player" src="c:/test.mp3" controls autoplay autobuffer>Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>

<audio id="player" src="file:///c:\test.mp3" controls autoplay autobuffer>Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>

<audio id="player" src="file:c:\test.mp3" controls autoplay autobuffer>Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>
```

etc. but nothing seems to work. Does anyone know why this is and if there is a workaround. I have spent hours trying different things and searching the web but no luck yet. I would greatly appreciate any help!

Thanks!

Comment: Why are the jquery and javascript tags here?

Comment: Because if there is a workaround for this to make it would probably be some form of JS.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve there but, AFAIK, this is not possible with modern browsers. It's not because that there's any technical problem doing this. It's just because the browser is preventing you from doing so.

If your web page is requesting some cross domain resource other than image, css, javascript, or requesting local resources, the browser will stop you because the browser vendor consider them as **unsafe** operations and may be abused to violate privacy if they're allowed.

So, in my understanding, you should stop what you're trying to do, because the only work around is to use and old unsafe browser which won't prevent you from doing anything (*but then it won't support HTML5*).

But of course, if you're just doing something to your own pleasure, you can choose to setup a simple web server on your PC and just host the media files *and* your web page together. You can choose nginx or apache (or IIS if your Windows version supports it) if you want a full utilized server, or just use SimpleHTTPServer in python if you're just making a personal toy.

Comment: Thanks for the info, this is only for personal use, I am just making a small music player, pretty much everything is done except for this one thing. I just really don't want to have to have two copies of all my music files, one where I store them on my PC and one where I am running the program from. 

I feel like there has to be some hack or way to get around this. I have seen similar things done where people stream things from PC locations to browser applications, I just don't know how it's done.

Comment: If you're using Linux or MacOS, this can be achieved by making symbolic links under your server document root. Shortcuts in windows won't do the job. If you want to stream local files you need to develop browser plugins or use other kind of application to host your media files in a HTTP manner.